# WinForms Button Displays Incorrect Image

Tags: image, winforms

I have a WinForms application and I'm using code to display an image on a button. The image corresponds to the record populating the form.  When the form data is loaded or refreshed it uses the key value from the record and is supposed to display a thumbnail created from the jpg associated with the record.  It grabs the correct jpg; but, when the thumbnail is created, it is displaying the wrong image on the button.  The problem does not occur on all files, just some.  It cannot use a image list because the images are editable and there are currently 8,000 records with corresponding images.

Anyone have some thoughts on what to look for in the JPG, or should I use a different control type?

Thank you in advance.

```
//Method called when form data is loaded or refreshed
private void RefreshImage()
{
    try
    {
        //Clear any current image
        btnViewImage.Image = null;

        string strNum = RecordDetailBDL.Data[KeyId].ToString();
        //Need to figure out how to store in and retrieve from the database
        string strDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageDirectoryLocation"];
        string defaultImage = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageDefaultFile"];
        string fileName = string.Empty;
        if (System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(strDirectory, strNum + ".jpg").Length > 0)
        {
            fileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}{2}", strDirectory, strNum, ".jpg");
        }
        else
        {
            fileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", strDirectory, defaultImage);
        }

        if (fileName != string.Empty)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fileName, true);
            System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort imgAbort = new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ImageCallbackAbort);
            //Create a thumbnail from the file that is slightly smaller than the button height and width
            System.Drawing.Image thumbNail = img.GetThumbnailImage((btnViewImage.Width - 5), (btnViewImage.Height - 5), imgAbort, IntPtr.Zero);
            btnViewImage.Image = thumbNail;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy fix here was for me to replace the control with a PictureBox.  With that control using the Load(filename) method, it displayed the correct image 100% of the time.